# Passing an object to serializer gives 'serializer: Unable to get repr for <class 'MyModel.serializers.MyModelSerializer'>

Tags: django, python-3.x, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm getting this error in debugger but the actual response I get from this endpoint is correct. When I pass an existing object from DB to serializer i get this error (shown below in code sample). This is a create API view that gets POST data then checks if that object exists in DB. If it does exist then returns that object, otherwise proceeds to create it.

```
class CreateMyModel(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         try:
             obj = MyModel.objects.get(uuid=request.data.get('uuid'))
             serializer = self.get_serializer(obj) <-- *serializer: Unable to get repr for <class 'MyModel.serializers.MyModelSerializer'>* 
             return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
         except ObjectDoesNotExist:
             return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    field1 = models.TextField()
    field2 = models.ForeignKey(SomeOtherModel)

    def __str__:
       return str(self.uuid)
```

Comment: Can you please add your serializer?

Answer (score 0):

You do not really need to overwrite the post method. [.ListCreateAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview) has two `list` and `create` actions that are triggered when making get and post requests respectively. So this is only needed:

```
class CreateMyModel(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
     serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
     queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
     permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
     authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
```

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that Hugo, but the android device that's consuming this API works in this manner so I can't change it...